# Get difference in lines of code between 2 commits by date Git

Tags: git, version-control, git-branch

I'm new to git and need help with a command.

So I have cloned a repository in Git, and I want to see the difference in insertions and deletions between 2 commits closest to 2 dates.

I know how to get the history commit by commit between 2 dates like bellow:

```
$ git log --since "JAN 1 2014" --until "DEC 31 2014" --oneline --shortstat origin/master
```

But how can I compare 2 commits  the first closest to JAN 1 2014 and the second closest to DEC 31 2014 and get the total difference between all files in both commit versions? Not commit by commit and add upp the total difference but only the difference in commit 1 (Jan 1) and commit 2 (Dec 31) and skip all the commits in between those commits, in one line like for example

```
51647f3: 340 files changed, 1316 insertions(+), 6676 deletions(-)
```

Also another question, does the insertions also include modded lines or just actual new lines?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `git diff` and provide [a range of commits](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Revision-Selection#Commit-Ranges) using the `..` notation:

```
git diff <firstcommit>..<secondcommit> --shortstat
```

In Git a commit points to a *snapshot* of the repository's directories and files. When you compare two commits you're actually comparing the *state of the files* as they were at different points in time, regardless of how many commits (i.e. "snapshots") have happened in between.

You can find the SHA-1 hash of the first commit that occurred *after* or *before* a specific date starting from `origin/master` by using [`git rev-list`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-rev-list.html):

```
git rev-list --since="jan 1 2014" --reverse origin/master | head -1
git rev-list --until="dec 31 2014" -n 1 origin/master
```

where `head` is used in the first case instead of the `-n` switch to select only the first line in the output. The reason is that `--reverse` is applied [after the filtering options](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-rev-list.html):

> Note that these are applied before commit ordering and formatting
>   options, such as `--reverse`.

As for your second question, according to the [unified diff format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diff_utility#Unified_format), a modified line counts as an insertion (`+`) for the new line and as a deletion (`-`) for the old one:

```
+ This is a modified line
- This is a line
```

So it will count for both.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, seems to work. However I just want to make sure that it only compare my to 2 commits against each other and not counting the commits in between (Like sums up the added/deleted files)? Also is there a more "user friendly" version of the above command instead of first having to find the first the commit nearest Dec 31 in the list above and then having to scroll down to the bottom of the list and then find the first commit?

Comment: The reason I'm asking for the "user friendly" is because I'm going to automize this on several repos, and I don't want dump everything to a text file and then find the first row and then the second row and then run another command. Thanks

Comment: @anders Sure. I've added a couple of commands to retrieve the SHA-1 hashes of the commits at the edges of the range.